# Attempting to understand how to program an array in C

Tags: c

So I was going through the "learn C the hard way" online book and I decided to test my skills with this program. I want to make it so the user can enter in a letter and see if it matches any of the characters in the secret word so they can guess it. Should I be using the `if else` statements inside the for statement? Also I can't get the program to tell me I got the letter write even though I enter it in correctly.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    /*Declaring the variables the user needs. One for the
      the user enters and the other for the secret word.*/

    char user_inputted_letter[1];
    char  secret_word[] = {'Q','u','a','l','m'};

    printf("See if you can guess the secret 5 letter word, if you enter in a letter \n"
            "that matches a letter in the secret word it will be displayed in \n"
            "a random order for you to guess! \n"); 

    scanf("%s",user_inputted_letter);
    printf("Your user inputted letter is %s \n",user_inputted_letter);

    /*for statement  to  scan each of the characters
      in secret_word. If statement detects if there is a match
      between the secret character and inputed value */
    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i < 6;i++)
    {
        if(secret_word[i] == user_inputted_letter[1]){
            printf("The matching letter you entered with the secret word is %s \n",user_inputted_letter);
        }
        else
            printf("There were no matching letters with the secret word\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the book say anything about arrays starting at index 0?

Comment: Few things - arrays start at index 0, not 1. Second, because your input only has room for one character, anything you enter will cause a buffer overflow; you need a second slot for the null terminator.

Comment: You can also initialize the character array with `char  secret_word[] = "Qualm";`. You may find that easier when dealing with strings. Just note that will create a constant literal that is null-terminated (which is required if you want to handle `secret-word` as a string). Meaning that the total length of `secret-word` will be `6` instead of `5`. (it will not change the remainder of your code)

Comment: Another decent read for C is [**The C Book**](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need more room for input. Replace the

```
char user_inputted_letter[1];
```

with

```
char user_inputted_letter[100];
```

Second, you need to compare all the characters. Replace

```
if(secret_word[i] == user_inputted_letter[1]){
```

with

```
if(secret_word[i] == user_inputted_letter[i]){
```

and (as you only hav 5 chars)

```
for(i=0; i < 6;i++)
```

with

```
for(i=0; i < 5;i++)
```